# Tomar dos valores mediante un sólo scaneo al usuario

Tags: java

Error "Cannot find symbol" al tomar dos valores separados por espacio:
Por ejemplo el usuario escribe: 20 100
Se pretende tomar el 20 en una variable y el 100 en otra variable. (siempre en 2 variable y no más).

```
import java.util.*;
public class separadoporespacio {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Introduce dos numeros separados por espacios: ");
       String mayormenor = myObj.nextLine();
       String[1]  = str.split(" ");
       double menor = Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]);
       double mayor = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
   }
}
```

Comment: ¿Querías poner esto? `String[] tokens = str.split(" ");`

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que tendrias que hacerlo asi

```
Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Introduce dos numeros separados por espacios: ");
String str = myObj.nextLine();
// String[1]  = str.split(" "); No se deberia definir el tamaño del array ya que al usar el split no sabes la dimension que tendrá
// Segundo que no tenias una variable definida despues de String[1]
String[] mayormenor = str.split(" ");
double menor = Double.parseDouble(mayormenor[0]);
double mayor = Double.parseDouble(mayormenor[1]);
System.out.println("mayor: " + mayor + ", menor: " + menor);
```

Comment: Hola! podrías añadir una explicación de lo que cambiaste en el código y porque? :)

Comment: Claro ahora lo edito